# Append and remove element with jquery when width of window is greater than 769px

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, append

I'm trying something a bit different with slideshows when the window width reduces and expands in size. I have the html code for two slideshows in slideshows.html. Slideshows are labeled:

```
<div class="slideshow-mobile">... </div>

<div class="slideshow-desktop">... </div>
```

I'd like to append '.slideshow-desktop', located in slideshow.html, into my '#featured' div, which is located index.html page, when the window width is greater than 769px.

When the window width is less than 769px, I'd like to remove the code from the existing slideshow,'.slideshow-desktop', and then append '.slideshow-mobile' in #featured. In other words when window width is less than 769px I just want to replace '.slideshow-desktop' with '.slideshow-mobile'.

I hope this makes since.
Would anyone know, or have a clue on how to do this?

Comment: Are you asking 1)about how to do the ajax or 2)how to do the append in jquery or 3)how to detect window width or 4)how to change the display when the user adjusts the width of their browser?

Comment: I'm too savvy with javascript or ajax.. so I'm not sure what would be more appropriate to use. Currently this is what I'm working with:
I'll write it below in a separate comment

Comment: This is what i'm working with right now... 
if (screen.width >= 769) {
   $(document).ready(function(e) {
      e.preventDefautl();
      var href = $(this).attr('slideshow.html');
      $('#featured').append(href = '.slideshow-desktop')
   });
   $('.slideshow-mobile').remove();
   return false;
} 
  
else{
   $(document).ready(function(e) {
      e.preventDefautl();
      var href = $(this).attr('slideshow.html');
      $('#featured').append(href = '.slideshow-mobile')
   });
    $('.slideshow-desktop').remove();
   return false;
};

Comment: you might have to copy and paste that code into a text editor.. it is kind of hard to read

Comment: why don't you use media queries? http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-css3-mediaqueries-20120619/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using Adapt.js (http://adapt.960.gs/), it has a callback function where you can add/remove elements in dependency of width.